# Pytest fixture for metaclass

Tags: python, pytest, metaclass

Is there an elegant way to define fixtures which are set before class creation, so that a metaclass could use them?
More precisley, in my use case I have a metaclass which creates the class according to some settings made on module level file.

settings.py:

```
SETTING_1 = True
SETTING_2 = False
...
```

In my tests I want to change some settings in a fixture and according to these settings my metaclass should create the class.

I have not found something about it in the docs.

Comment: Is the metaclass which will consume the fixtures in your test code, or on your application code?

Answer (score 0):

Metaclasses,as well as classes making use of those metaclasses, are created when the lines of code containing the `class` statement body is executed.

With this in mind, there is nothing different in testing classes or metaclasses - if the class statement is at module level, classes and metaclasses will be build when the module is first imported - which means you'd have to go out of your (or the test framewrok's) way to have then rebuilt between tests.

But if you do put those inside function bodies, they will be rebuilt when the functions are called. If they are fixture functions, each time the fixture is used, they are rebuilt (although I think Pytest do some fixture caching - beware of that)

On the other hand, if the metaclasses and the classes that use then are in the application code, then you can't put then inside function bodies to be recreated. In this case, you will have to architect a carefull use of the `imp.reload` function - this will make that the code at module level is re-run at each invocation. You could call `imp.reload(<module>)` inside your fixture functions, but be careful to rebind any references to those metaclasses (and classes that use them) during the fixture run.

So, if your application code is something along:

```
# module_b
from module_a import SETTING_1, SETTING_2

class Meta(type):
    def __init__(mcls, name, bases, ns, **kw):
         # code that make use of SETTING_1 and SETTING_2
         ...

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    ...
```

test fixtures module:

```
import pytest
from unittest import mock

@pytest.fixture
def recreate_metaclass():
    from imp import reload
    # Drawback: fixtures file have to know and manually imported here 
    import test_module_1, ...
    import module_b
    with mock.patch("module_a.SETTING_1", val_1), mock.patch("module_a.SETTING_2" val_2):
        module_b = reload(module_b)
        # rebind module_a inside test modules
        test_module_1.module_b = module_b
        ...
```